# Using integers for "quoting" parameter in csv module

Tags: python, csv

The [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module defines the constants `QUOTE_ALL`, `QUOTE_MINIMAL`, `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, `QUOTE_NONE`, which are used in the `quoting` keyword argument, for instance:

```
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
```

But it appears that this keyword equally accepts integers between 0-3, which map to QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or QUOTE_NONE (3). (I found this in [the documentation of the Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)):

```
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=2)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
```

Using a number greater than 3 yields a `TypeError: bad "quoting" value`.

But I can't find this behaviour documented anywhere (the Python `csv` documentation just says that the module defines these constants), nor can I find it in the source code for the `csv` library.

Is there some implicit mapping for constants I don't know about? How does this work, and is it documented?

Comment: Afaik, `csv.QUOTE...` are just names that explicit the effect of the values 0 - 3 (meaningful aliases if you wish).

Comment: I think the `csv.write` `quoting` parameter is part of the [Dialect parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) which mentions that it can accept `QUOTE_*` constants. Although the documentation doesn't specify which integer value the constants were mapped to since it expects to be among the `QUOTE_*` constants mapped value so using the number outside of the expected value would cause `TypeError` exception be raised

Comment: Implementing enums as aliases to ints is a very common technique. But it is an implementation detail deliberately not documented since you don't want users of an API (like the csv module) to substitute integers rather than use the symbolic enum constant. Are you asking how to define such enums in your own code? If so google "python enum class".

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is documented in the description of [`Dialect.quoting`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quoting):

> It can take on any of the `QUOTE_*` constants (see section [Module Contents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-contents)) and defaults to `QUOTE_MINIMAL`.

When it says that it can take any of those constants, it implicitly means that any other values are invalid.

Comment: But I'm not asking why other values are invalid, I'm asking why (undocumented) _integers_ work instead of the constants.

Comment: The constants have to have some values, and those happen to be the values.

Comment: Maybe it's just that I am a Python programmer without a background in C and Java, but when I hear the term "constant" I don't assume it has to have a value. E.g. I would refer to the expression `QUOTES = "minimal"` at the top of a module as a constant, but the only value it as has is a string.

Comment: `"minimal"` is a value. Integers are usually used because they're more efficient. Just like `enum` in C.

Answer (score 1):

The CPython source code for the CSV module ([`cpython/Lib/csv.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/csv.py)) imports the constants from a file called `_csv`:

```
from _csv import QUOTE_MINIMAL, QUOTE_ALL, QUOTE_NONNUMERIC...
```

I thought `_csv` was a Python file and couldn't find it on my local installation, but it is in the source code, in [`Modules/csv.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_csv.c)

```
typedef enum {
    QUOTE_MINIMAL, QUOTE_ALL, QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, QUOTE_NONE,
    QUOTE_STRINGS, QUOTE_NOTNULL
} QuoteStyle;
```

And it exists on my local installation in compiled form, as a shared library binary.¹

So here is the implicit mapping between these constants and integers, since an enum in C is [by definition](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Enumerations) a data type that stores named integers.

The equivalent in the [enum module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) in Python is not too different. If I create an Enum:

```
from enum import Enum

Color = Enum('Color', ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'])
```

I can refer to `Color.RED`, and also to an integer e.g. `Color(1)`.

So this explains the *how*. As to why it is undocumented, as others have said here I guess it is not intended to be used. It is a little surprising that Pandas' `read_csv` relies on this with a default value of `quoting=0`. But Pandas, like Numpy, is pretty tightly coupled with CPython since it relies on a lot of C code, so maybe it makes sense to rely on specific quirks of the CPython implementation.

---

¹On my machine (Homebrew Python on macOS) it is in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_csv.cpython-311-darwin.so`